# How to use Laravel's factory/faker with a model that has a constructor with parameters?

Tags: laravel, constructor, model, factory, faker

I'm new to working with laravel's factory/faker dummy data generation. I'm curious as to how I can run my factory, from tinker, and have it use a model's constructor that (in this case) takes two integer parameters.

My research, on S.O. and Googs, has failed to point me in the right direction for dealing with this particular situation. The code that follows is only for testing/edu, that's why I tried using a service provider (which could be the problem).

Here's the set up, I have my model:

**Doombot.php**

```
class Doombot extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public $model_id;
    public $weapon_id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct(int $model_id, int $weapon_id)
    {
        $this->model_id = $model_id;
        $this->weapon_id = $weapon_id;
    }
}
```

I have a service provider to initialize a newly created (typehinted) Doombot, passing the constructors arguments:

**DoombotsServiceProvider.php**

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(Doombot::class, function(){

        $model_id = random_int(1, 2);
        $weapon_id = random_int(1, 2);

        return new Doombot($model_id, $weapon_id);

    });
}
```

So now when I create a Doombot, I have the parameters set within my object. Great. Then I have my factory:

**DoombotsFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(Doombot::class, function (Faker $faker) {

   return [
        'model_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 2),
        'weapon_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 2),
        'name' => $faker->firstName
    ];
});
```

When I run the above in Tinker using:

```
factory(App\Doombot::class)->make()
```

I get:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App/Doombot::__construct() must be of the type integer, 
>   array given, called in /FactoryBuilder.php on line 292

But if I comment out my models constructor my `make()` calls produce the expected results:

```
App\Doombot {#2942
     model_id: 2,
     weapon_id: 2,
     name: "Dannie",
   }
```

What makes sense to me is that the DoombotsFactory is trying to create a Doombot when returning, without using the Service Provider, just by using values within the array. So the objects actual constructor call occurs on `return [<array_values>]`? Is this line of thinking correct?

But is there any way to have it use the service provider so that the proper parameters are already set for each newly created dummy record?

Essentially, I'd like to just be using faker to produce a name: (Removing the `'<field_name>' => $faker->numberBetween(1,2)` nodes didn't help.)

**Hypothetical DoombotsFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(Doombot::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    // create doombot object with the parameters set upon creation
    $obj = new Doombot;   

    // Since model_id and weapon_id have been set, add the name property
    $obj->name => $faker->firstName

    // somehow return this, but I believe only arrays are allowed
    return $obj;

});
```

Comment: Have you actually tested this model?  I wouldn't worry about the factory yet.   Eloquent is an activerecord ORM that uses an attributes array to maintain database fields, using real properties and overwriting the constructor likely won't work.

Comment: I was able to test the model, and dd() the object itself to see that the properties are being set correctly. If I understand the second part of your comment, I would have to comment out any constructors my models had in order to inject my dummy data?

Comment: The properties being set weren't really my concern, were the properties persisted to the database?

Comment: If I comment out the constructor, I can user create() to persist them from tinker.

Comment: I don't think so.. since eloquent won't know which properties relate to your database table

Comment: Maybe that's the normal behavior https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12345, have you done something differently?